# simple jquery trim input down to 2 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, trim

I'm wanting to take whatever is entered into input and when the button is clicked, it removes everything after the first two characters that were entered.

For example if I entered in "BT2J43" I would like it to cut it down to "BT" in the input field is the possible?

Here's my fiddle below, I'm just learn jquery, go easy on me!

https://jsfiddle.net/ktd9gbu9/1/

```
$("#submit123").click(function() {
  $("#text123").text($("#text123")[0].innerText.substr(2));
});

<input type="search" name="table_filter" id="text123" required>
<input name="submit" type="Submit" id="submit123" value="Search">
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`:

```
$("#submit123").click(function () {
    $("#text123").val($("#text123").val().substr(0, 2));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ktd9gbu9/2/)**

Also with substr() you forgot the starting index.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily but you need to target `.val()`

Here is a clean code that may help you! :)

```
$("#button").click(function () {
    var search = $("#search");
    search.val(search.val().substr(0, 2));
});
```

There you go with [JSfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/29vw2gnr/)